# Can't send json message to AWS SQS from cURL POST

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have the AWS SDK for PHP installed in the webserver and can create a queue, send/delete a test message. I then tried to check if I can send a json (text or object) from using curl. Somehow it's not getting the message. If I change the variable ($json) in the 'MessageBody' to a string and run the php script manually, the string gets forwarded to the queue. Any ideas?

```
<?php

require 'SQS/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

header("Content-Type: application/json");

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
error_log( print_r( $json, true ));

$client = new SqsClient([
'profile' => 'default',
'region' => 'us-east-1',
'version' => 'latest'
]);

$client->sendMessage(array(
'QueueUrl'    => "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx",
'MessageBody' => $json
));
```

Here is the cURL request:

curl -v http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/somesite/somescript.php -d '{"hello":"world"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"

Comment: what is the result of `sendMessage()`? Your curl syntax looks fine and your usage of `'php://input'` checks out

Comment: How do I check that? I also tried to output the json from the 'php://input' to the error log but nothing shows up. As if it's not even being accepted. I get a 200 response from curl though.

Comment: wrap your `$client->sendMessage()` call with `vardump()` function or do a result assignment `$result = $client->sendMessage(....; vardump($result);`

Comment: @HenryN. Did you resolve this? I have a very similar problem (posted on here recently) and I'm not getting any response on it. Would love to know if you got it working! 
My Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73259556/error-when-calling-aws-lambda-from-php-script-hosted-on-apache-but-can-from-same)